# Mysql Like characters [a-z] or Zero

Tags: mysql, character, sql-like

In a mysql table i have column whit this info..

```
Col.
tr10
tr210
zbr10
00010
10010
tr 10
```

The question is simple, i need to find in a mysql query all the records number  10.. but as you can see in the example not 10010 etc..

```
Result:
tr10
zbr10
00010
tr 10
```

I know is a mess but the records had to be load in that form..

so you have characters at the begining, in some cases spaces, or zeros..

An option could be extract (by hand) hundred of characters to another column to keep the things less complex, but at the same time i still having problems with the 000010 values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions

```
select * from table where col regexp '^[a-z]+10$'
```

Play with the regex until you get your desired results, i didnt fully understand you criteria so I just made one up but the one in my example will pull all the rows with any alpha characters proceeded by 10

Comment: The criteria is simple, find all the 10, if has number 00010 is in fact.. a ten..  if is tr 10, in fact is 10 too with a nomenclator at the begining.. your example is good.. i will have to play with! thanks!